# Is there a global way to fix json in blazor program .cs everything I try doesnt work

Tags: c#, blazor

At present, I am using Blazor and .NET 8, and the issue I am having is that the JSON being brought back is in lowercase, but my model is expected in normal case.

For example, if I have the following code, you can see that I am defining the JsonPropertyName property.

By the way am using System.Text.Json not the other way.

```
public class StockItem : BaseEntity
{
    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string? Name { get; set; }      
    [JsonPropertyName("fullDescription")]
    public string FullDescription { get; set; }
}
```

I also tried setting the popertynaming policy globally

```
builder.Services.Configure<JsonSerializerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
});
```

But this did not work for me JsonPropertyName works but it seems very counter productive having to do this for every class.

Example Json

```
[{"id":3,"storeId":null,"userId":null,"stockCode":"ABCDE","supplierId":null,"barCode":"2342342","shortDescription":null,"price":"39.69","name":"Test Product 1","fullDescription":"THIS IS AN APPLE PRODUCT","categories":null,"manufactures":null,"availableStartDate":null,"availableEndDate":null,"isShowCallButton":false,"isNew":false,"adminComment":null,"tags":null,"gtin":null,"manufacturePartNo":null,"isShowOnHomePage":null,"stockItemType":null,"isShowPrice":null,"canAddToCart":null,"showCallForPrice":null,"warehouseLocation":null,"productType":null,"isPublished":null,"defaultPrice":null,"priceList":null,"priceListType":null,"sku":null,"isFeatured":null,"isBackOrder":null,"isDeleted":false,"isActive":true,"createdBy":null,"createdDate":null,"lastUpdateDate":null}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deserialize can be called with options.

```cs
JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions 
{ 
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase 
};
StockItem[] items = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<StockItem[]>(jsonString, options);
```

I confirmed this with a .net 8.0 console app with the `JsonPropertyName` attributes removed.

You cannot set the default value for the serializer. You can create a new Converter with your desired options and Inject that.

Comment: Still not really a global thing but a guess just a stupid limitation silly this day and age

Comment: @c-sharp-and-swiftui-devni I think it is to do with thread safe security